# How can Nokia S-40 series C1-01 support JSR 256

Tags: java-me

Is there any packages available or something relevant to make Nokia S-40 series mobile to support sensor related applications by JSR-256??

Answer (score 1):

It can not. Sensors are about hardware also. A device that does not have the hardware can not also have the API.

Answer (score 0):

Targeting a S40 device that supports sensors. For example the Asha 311 have JSR-256 API available, using the 2.0 SDK.